# Returning an array completed from an array.push inside a firebase foreach

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, promise, google-cloud-functions

i'm having bad time with nodejs (v6.14.0) at this moment, because i made a post request that have to do some work until return a valid response. The problem is that i get an empty array as response (if i rerun more than once the request the response will be valid), i have researched and need to manage how te promises are resolved and returned but i can't see what i need to do because i see this a bit more complex that the examples that i found, i need a more deeper advice or guide please. This is my code:

```
ru.post('/route', (request, response) => {
let rBody = request.body;
let weekDay = getDay(rBody.date);  // Return day => "Monday"
let cRef = adminDb.database().ref('/fields/');
return cRef.orderByChild('field_size').equalTo(rBody.type).once('value').then((snap) => {
    let arrResult = new Array;
    snap.forEach(fields => {
        infoField = fields.val();
        let idFi = infoField.id_fi;
        let idCen = infoField.id_cen;
        let id_rsvp = idFi + "_" + rBody.date + "_" + idCen;
        let id_rsvp2 = idFi + "_" + rBody.date + "_" + idCen + "_" + rBody.hour;
        let resRef = adminDb.database().ref('/rsvp/' + id_rsvp + '/' + id_rsvp2);
        resRef.on('value', snap => {
            if (snap.val() === null) {
                if (infoField.act === "true") {
                    let cenRef = adminDb.database().ref('/cen/' + idCen);
                    cenRef.on('value', snap => {
                        let infoCen = snap.val();
                        if (infoCen.act === "true") {
                            values = infoField.ft;
                            daySelected = weekDay;
                            dayCheck = values[daySelected];
                            hourSelected = rBody.hour;
                            hourCheck = dayCheck[hourSelected];
                            if (hourCheck !== "" && hourCheck !== "0") {
                                infoField.lat = infoCen.lat;
                                infoField.lon = infoCen.long;
                                if (rBody.lat !== undefined && rBody.long !== undefined) {
                                    infoField.dGet = true;
                                } else {
                                    infoField.dGet = false;
                                }
                                infoField.address = infoCen.address;
                                uRef = adminDb.database().ref('/users/');
                                uRef.child(rBody.userid).child('/fav/').orderByChild('id_fi').equalTo(idFi).on('value', snap => {
                                    if (snap.exists() === true) {
                                        infoField.fav = true
                                    } else {
                                        infoField.fav = false
                                    }
                                    arrResult.push(infoField); //how to get this arrResult (completed) to use on the next .then() on first try?
                                })
                            }
                        }
                    })
                }
            }
        })
    })
    return arrResult;
}).then((res) => {
    console.log("check",res);
    return response.status(200).json(res); // Fist response is [], if it a new request with the same values it works...
}).catch(err => {
    return response.status(err.status >= 100 && err.status < 600 ? err.code : 500).send(err.message);
})});
```

Resulting array must be something like this at fist try:

```
[{
//Values from first snapshot return (infoField) plus:
lat: infoCen.lat,
lon: infoCen.long,
dGet: true/false,
address: infoCen.address,
fav: true/false,
}]
```

I only get that after second running, at first one it keeps as empty []

Answer (score 1):

I made some edits to your code, you are not handling promises correctly:

```
ru.post('/route', (request, response) => {
  let rBody = request.body;
  let weekDay = getDay(rBody.date); // Return day => "Monday"
  let cRef = adminDb.database().ref('/fields/');
  return cRef.orderByChild('field_size').equalTo(rBody.type).once('value').then((snapshot) => {
    let arrResult = [];
    snapshot.forEach(fields => {
      let infoField = fields.val();
      let idFi = infoField.id_fi;
      let idCen = infoField.id_cen;
      let id_rsvp = idFi + "_" + rBody.date + "_" + idCen;
      let id_rsvp2 = idFi + "_" + rBody.date + "_" + idCen + "_" + rBody.hour;
      let resRef = adminDb.database().ref('/rsvp/' + id_rsvp + '/' + id_rsvp2);
      return resRef.on('value', snap => {
        if (snap.val() === null) {
          if (infoField.act === "true") {
            let cenRef = adminDb.database().ref('/cen/' + idCen);
            return cenRef.on('value', snap => {
              let infoCen = snap.val();
              if (infoCen.act === "true") {
                let values = infoField.ft;
                let daySelected = weekDay;
                let dayCheck = values[daySelected];
                let hourSelected = rBody.hour;
                let hourCheck = dayCheck[hourSelected];
                if (hourCheck !== "" && hourCheck !== "0") {
                  arrResult.push(adminDb.database().ref('/fields/' + fields.key + '/lat').set(infoCen.lat));
                  arrResult.push(adminDb.database().ref('/fields/' + fields.key + '/lon').set(infoCen.long));
                  if (rBody.lat !== undefined && rBody.long !== undefined) {
                    arrResult.push(adminDb.database().ref('/fields/' + fields.key + '/dGet').set(true));
                  } else {
                    arrResult.push(adminDb.database().ref('/fields/' + fields.key + '/distanciaGet').set(false));
                  }
                  arrResult.push(adminDb.database().ref('/fields/' + fields.key + '/address').set(infoCen.address));
                  const uRef = adminDb.database().ref('/users/');
                  uRef.child(rBody.userid).child('/fav/').orderByChild('id_fi').equalTo(idFi).on('value', snap => {
                    if (snap.exists() === true) {
                      arrResult.push(adminDb.database().ref('/fields/' + fields.key + '/fav').set(true));
                    } else {
                      arrResult.push(adminDb.database().ref('/fields/' + fields.key + '/fav').set(false));
                    }
                  });
                }
              }
            });
          }
        }
      });
    });
    return Promise.all(arrResult);
  }).then((res) => {
    console.log("check", res);
    return response.status(200).json(res); // Fist response is [], if it a new request with the same values it works...
  }).catch(err => {
    return response.status(err.status >= 100 && err.status < 600 ? err.code : 500).send(err.message);
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer yes it has to do with how i'm handling promises but i cannot figure how to resolve it.
Ok, i tried your answer but it returns an array of [{true,true,false}] also it returns empty at first try then on second/third one it get filled (the same behaviour that i want to resolve). I have updated my question on how the returning array should looks like at first try.

Comment: please test now and let me know

Comment: Hello! just tried it, results on the same behaviour it returns empty at first try then on second/third one it get filled, it isn't waiting to complete te work, tested with some logs on the above foreach and those are executed before the response part can't figure why yet, and also tried to modify to test further but till now i can't get it work. 

Also, when i set return on line #14 `return resRef.on('value', snap =>` the foreach its only evaluate once resulting on only one item that can't be.